# Separability and reduced tensor fields

Tags: extension-field, tensor-products

Let $L/K$ be a finite field extension. I need to prove that if $L/K$ is separable, then $E\otimes_KL$ is reduced for every algebraic field extension $E/K$.

I've readed that I need to use the Primitive Element Theorem and then the Chinesse Remainder Theorem, but I just don't see it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $L/K$ is a finite separable extension, there is a $\theta\in L$ such that $L=K(\theta)$ by the primitive element theorem. Let $P$ be the minimal polynomial of $\theta$ over $K$. Let $E/K$ be any field extension, algebraic or not. Since $\theta$ is separable over $K$, the irreducible polynomial $P$ is a separable polynomial. This means that all the roots of $P$ in any extension of $K$ are simple. Let
$$
P=P_1^{e_1}\cdots P_r^{e_r}
$$
be the decomposition of $P$ in irreducible factors in $E[X]$. Since $P$ is separable, all $e_i$ are equal to $1$. It follows that
$$
E\otimes_KL=E\otimes_K(K[X]/(P))=(E\otimes_KK[X])/(P)=E[X]/(P)=\prod_{i=1}^r E[X]/(P_i)
$$
by the Chinese remainder theorem. Since the $P_i$ are irreducible in $E[X]$, the product above is a product of fields. In particular, it is reduced.

Comment: Although yesterday It wasn't clear for me that $E\otimes_K(K[x]/(P)=(E\otimes_KK[x])/(P)=E[x]/(P)$, I thought I could easily prove it. I've been trying it (establishing an isomorphism) but haven't been capable. Can you sketch the reason please?

Comment: One has the exact sequence $$(P)\rightarrow K[X]\rightarrow K[X]/(P)\rightarrow 0$$ which gives

Comment: ...the exact sequence $$E\otimes_K(P)\rightarrow E\otimes_KK[X]\rightarrow E\otimes_K(K[X]/(P))\rightarrow0.$$ The image of the first morphism of the latter exact sequence is the ideal generated by $P$ in the ring $E\otimes_KK[X]=E[X]$. Therefore $$E\otimes_K(K[X]/(P))=E[X]/(P),$$ where the latter $(P)$ is the ideal generated in $E[X]$ of course.

Comment: I've been only working with module tensors only foor a few days, so please forgive

Comment: ... if this is so trivial as it looks like but, why is it $E\otimes_KK[x]=E[x]$?

Comment: This is best shown by proving that $E\otimes_KK[x]$ satisfies the same universal property as $E[x]$. The universal property in question is the following. For any $E$-algebra $A$ and for any element $a\in A$ there is exactly one morphism of $E$-algebras $f\colon E[x]\rightarrow A$ such that $f(x)=a$. Indeed, one must have $f(p)=p(a)$ for all $p\in E[x]$. In order to show that $E\otimes_KK[x]$, with the pereferred element $1\otimes x$, does also satisfy this universal property, let $A$ be an $E$-algebra and let $a\in A$.

Comment: SInce $A$ is also a $K$-algebra, there is a morphism $g\colon K[x]\rightarrow A$ of $K$-algebras such that $g(x)=a$, by the universal property of $K[x]$. Since $A$ is an $E$-algebra, there is a morphism $f\colon E\otimes_KK[x]\rightarrow A$ of $E$-algebras such that $f(1\otimes p)=g(p)$ for all $p\in K[x]$. In particular, $f(1\otimes x)=g(x)=a$. One checks unicity of $f$ as follows. Let $h\colon E\otimes_KK[x]\rightarrow A$ be another morphism of $E$-algebras such that $h(1\otimes x)=a$. Then, $h(1\otimes p)=p(a)=g(p)$ for all $p\in K[x]$. Hence $h=f$ by the unicity of $f$ as being induced by

Comment: Crystal-clear. Thank u!! :)